# Jasper Soft Excel Column issues

Tags: jasper-reports

I have 8 sub reports that are placed on a main report which has 
"print.one .page.per.sheet" enabled.
And after each sub report net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row property enabled (for printing each sub report in a new work sheet)
While exporting each report to excel individually every columns in the excel sheet matches the columns of the report.
But after placing it in the main report excel columns overlap with report columns.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution with excel to put the individual sub reports in different sheets is to not use main report but pass the JasperPrint of the different sub reports as different sheets.

**Example**

```
List<JasperPrint> sheets = new ArrayList<JasperPrint>();
for (int i=1;i<=8;i++){
   JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport("subReport_" + i + ".jasper", paramMap, connection);
   sheets.add(print); 
}

JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
exporter.setExporterInput(SimpleExporterInput.getInstance(sheets));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(new File("text.xlxs"));
SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimpleXlsxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setSheetNames(sheetNames): //sheets names is an array of the different names.
configuration.setDetectCellType(true);
configuration.setWhitePageBackground(false);
configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenColumns(true);
configuration.setRemoveEmptySpaceBetweenRows(true);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```